# What is the explanation for R and SQL connection code here?

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rstudio

This is a function that I found online to be used in R. Can somebody explain it to me how to use it in R, if I have to run a .sql file extension through R

```
getSQL <- function(filepath) {
    con = file(filepath, "r")
    sql.string <- ""

    while (TRUE) {
        line <- readLines(con, n = 1)

        if ( length(line) == 0 ) {
            break
        }
        line <- gsub("\\t", " ", line)
        if (grepl("--",line) == TRUE) {
            line <- paste(sub("--", "/*", line), "*/")
        }
        sql.string <- paste(sql.string, line)
    }
    close(con)

    return(sql.string)
}
```

Comment: @matt-jewet can you provide an explanation for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function appears to be reading in some SQL text file, and then doing some processing on it.  Specifically, the critical logic seems to be these lines of code:

```
line <- gsub("\\t", " ", line)
if (grepl("--", line) == TRUE) {
    line <- paste(sub("--", "/*", line), "*/")
}
sql.string <- paste(sql.string, line)
```

First, all tabs (`\t`) are replaced by a single space.  Then, lines containing `--`, which presumably were comment-only lines, are replaced by `/*`, followed by the comment, followed by `*/`.  That is, `--` comments are converted to C/C++ style comments.  Then, the current line is added to the running SQL string.  And finally, the modified SQL string is returned from the function.

I don't know why you would be using this, but it basically is just modifying the whitespace and comments in a SQL script.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen